# Disabling cypress/unsafe-to-chain-command rule

Tags: cypress, eslint

I was updating our dependencies including `eslint-plugin-cypress`. In the new version `cypress/unsafe-to-chain-command` is enabled and I want ESLint to ignore this rule.

I added `"cypress/unsafe-to-chain-command": "off",` into rules in `.eslintrc.js` file but it didn't change anything. When I added `// eslint-disable-line cypress/unsafe-to-chain-command` in one specific place it worked as expected and I have no idea what the problem is. How could I handle this?

Comment: Please give a [mre] - `"cypress/unsafe-to-chain-command": "off"` _is_ how to disable it, but if that's subsequently overridden with `overrides` or a nested ESLint config file it will get turned back on.